# How to make a loop of sql queries?

Tags: julia

I'm trying to use the MySQL pkg to try and get the results for multiple queries so I wrote a loop:

```
db = connect_db()

variants_location = get_data_from_variant_file(variant_file)

query = MySQL.Stmt(db, """SELECT info
                          FROM hgmd_hg38_vcf
                          WHERE chrom = (?) AND pos = (?) AND ref = (?) AND alt = (?);""")

for loc in variants_location
    println(MySQL.execute!(query, loc))
end
```

Here is one element of the "variants_location" variable:
`SubString{String}["16", "2074320", "C", "A"]`

Is there a way to get the result of the execution of my query? I tried just printing it but it just returns a number.

Comment: Use [`MySQL.Query`](https://github.com/JuliaDatabases/MySQL.jl#mysqlquery), ie: _**To materialize the results as a `DataFrame`, use `MySQL.Query(conn, sql) |> DataFrame`.**_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the base of the documentation it seems that, `MySQL.jl` does not support precompiled SQL queries for selecting data (you can only use them `INSERT`, `DELETE`, `UPDATE`)

You have the following options:

- build the sql string and use the proposed above `MySQL.Query(conn, sql) |> DataFrame` pattern. This is however prone to SQL injection and requires compiling by the database the query every time.
- use the `INSERT` to store results in temporary table and than get them with the above pattern - this is somewhat ugly
- use either a Python or a Java driver via either `PyCall.jl` or `JDBC.jl` library. This requires more configuration but both Python and Java MySQL drivers support precompiled statements.

Comment: Using your first option, is it difficult to build the query string with variables in the middle? I know I had problems in Python doing that.
Is it as simple as that? Bearing in mind that the string would be in the loop:
`"SELECT info FROM hgmd_hg38_vcf WHERE chrom = loc[1] AND pos = loc[2] AND ref = loc[3] AND alt = loc[4];"`

Comment: Right now, I'm creating variables for each value I need from the variants_location list but it can't be the optimal way.
`chrom = loc[1]`
`pos = loc[2]`
`ref = loc[3]`
`alt = loc[4]`
`query_string = "SELECT info FROM hgmd_hg38_vcf WHERE chrom = $chrom AND pos = $pos AND ref = \"$ref\" AND alt = \"$alt\";"`

Comment: You can interpolated directly the array elements: `query_string = "SELECT info FROM hgmd_hg38_vcf WHERE chrom = $(loc[1]) AND pos = $(loc[2]) AND ref = \"$(loc[3])\" AND alt = \"$(loc[4])\";"`

Comment: Additionally, if you are processing user-generated data, consider using `MySQL.escape` function for the `String` values to avoid SQL injection.